# Maxima (or saddle points) of the free energy are thermodynamically stable phases?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, mean-field-theory

In classical mechanics, the equations of motions are derived following the principle of stationary action, i.e., by taking the minima, maxima, or saddle points of the action $\delta S=0$. The principle of stationary action historically replaced the principle of least action, where the equations of motions were derived by taking the minima of the action $S$ (excluding the maxima and saddle points). Now there are examples of systems (e.g., in optics) where the action takes a maximum or a saddle point, and not necessarily a minimum.

In statistical mechanics, there is a similar concept where the equilibrium states are those which minimize the free energy $F$ (or the relevant thermodynamic potential). Is there a similar generalization in this case, to a principle of "stationary energy"  $\delta F=0$ by including also maxima and saddle points of the free energy?

My doubt is motivated by the fact that in mean field theories, one effectively derives the so-called "self-consistent" equations by imposing $\delta F=0$. These self-consistent equations may be intuitively seen as enforcing a principle of "small fluctuations". Now, in principle, there may be cases where these self-consistent equations lead to a maximum of the free energy. Are there realistic examples where this happens? And in these cases, are these solutions physical or must be discarded? And why?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a remote possibility that mean field theories may have solutions corresponding to a maximum of free energy. It is the typical behavior below their critical point.

However, maxima of the free energy are just artifacts of the underlying approximation (in particular, they are consequences of the analytical character of the mean-field free energy). Indeed, the maxima  (or even saddle point) of the free energy as a function of its thermodynamic variables would imply a violation of its convexity properties. I recall that the convexity properties, on the one side, are direct consequences of the second principle of thermodynamics. On the other side, their violation would imply the presence of instabilities of the thermodynamic system incompatible with thermodynamic equilibrium.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the maxima of the free energy are not physical but just artifacts of the mean field approximation. Does this mean that if one could calculate the free energy of the system "exactly" (without approximations), there would be no maxima and no saddle points, but only one single minimum? What about metastable points corresponding to secondary minima? Intuitively, a function having several minima would also have maxima or saddle points between them (thinking for example to "Mexican hat" kind of landscapes)?

Comment: @sintetico we expect a unique thermodynamic equilibrium state. Therefore, the "exact" free energy should be consistent with such an expectation. Of course, from the statistical mechanic point of view, this requirement may be a constraint on the Hamiltonians. However, we may have *constrained* systems. adding metastable additional minima to the free energy. A typical constraint may be due to a slow kinetic exploration of the available phase space. This is the case of supercooled or superheated phases.

Answer (score -1):

As you point out: the earlier assumption of 'least action' had to be abandoned, in favor of a stationary action form.

As you point out: there are classes of cases such that the true trajectory corresponds to a maximum of the applicable action. That does not only present itself in Optics, classical mechanics has classes of cases such that the true trajectory corresponds to a maximum of Hamilton's action.

In the case of stationary action: in retrospect the name 'least action' was wishful thinking. The thing is: the shift of the name didn't come about through discovering new physics. It shouldn't have been named 'least action' in the first place. The first to propose the name 'stationary action' was William Rowan Hamilton himself. It's too bad that proposal wasn't followed.

In that sense there is a fundamental difference between the cases of Hamilton's action and the free energy concept of statistical mechanics.

Comment: Sorry, this is a useful comment historically clarifying the principle of stationary action vs least action, but it is not answering my question, which is about statistical mechanics.

Comment: Edited out "superseded" as per your suggestion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/423716)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I agree that it isn't an exhaustive answer. However, it does raise a relevant point. The question is whether there is a meaningful analogy between on one hand finding points in variation space where the derivative of Hamilton's action is zero; $\delta S = 0$, and on the other hand finding a state such that the derivative of some thermodynamic potential is zero: $\delta F = 0 $. In my answer I argue that the similarity is superficial only: on closer examination we see that the two cases are not analogous.

Answer (score -1):

In this answer I want to address the general issue of interpreting mathematical representation.

I will first discuss that for the context of mechanics, and then I will move to statistical mechanics.

An example of a true minimization problem is the [catenary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary).

If you nudge a catenary it will swing, the swinging motion dissipates energy, and the catenary settles onto an equilibrium position.

The strategy to find the shape of that curve capitalizes on a side effect: a function that has a minimum must have a point where its derivative is zero.

Finding the point where the derivative is zero is mathematically tractable.

The equation for the catenary offers two curves that satisfy the condition: the catenary and the [catenary arch](http://makingmathvisible.com/catenary/catenary-1.html).

The concept of a catenary arch is itself interesting, of course, but it here I use that to illustrate that caution is necessary. The catenary arch satisfies the condition: *derivative of integral of potential energy is zero*, but it's not a solution for the case of the hanging chain. Room for that spurious solution was introduced by the fact that rather than finding the minimum *directly* a side-effect was used; derivative is zero.

We have that the context of statistical mechanics introduces entropy as a factor that goes into equilibrium state

It seems to me:
while the catenary problem does not involve entropy, it can serve as an analogy for the free energy case.

(By contrast: I think optics (Fermat's stationary time) and mechanics (Hamilton's stationary action) cannot. This is what I had in mind in stating that there is a fundamental difference between Hamilton's action and thermodynamic free energy.)

Thermodynamic equilibrium is a true minimum, just as the hanging shape of a catenary is a true minimum.

I think I also need to address this difference: static equilibrium and dynamic equilibrium.

An example of dynamic equilibrium:
The shape of the mirror of a [Liquid Mirror Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-mirror_telescope)
When a bowl filled with liquid is in uniform rotation the surface takes on the form of a paraboloid of revolution. The circumnavigating fluid has kinetic energy and potential energy. The kinetic energy has no place to go; the potential energy has no place to go. The state of dynamic equilibrium is a state where there is no longer any opportunity to dissipate energy.

With all of the above in place:
I regard thermodynamic equilibrium as a dynamic state such that there is no longer opportunity to dissipate energy. We have equations for the processes that can occur.

It seems to me: solving for $\delta F = 0$ may introduce a spurious solution, a solution that corresponds to a maximum.

Comment: Still not answering my question, but only clarifies the meaning of the stationary principle (which is not what the question is asking).

Comment: @sintetico I knew of course that this answer was not an exhaustive answer. My hope was that it would give you clues to follow up. I disagree that this second answer is about 'stationary principle'. This second answer is about physical process of settling down onto an equilibrium state.

Comment: my point is that your answers are not answering my questions at all.